# Excel COUNTIF for comma separated values in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following range of values:

4

3,5,6

2

2,5

5

7,8,9,5

This means there can be more than one value in one column, separated by commas.

I want to count all 5s in this range. I have used the COUNTIF method but it seems not to be enough:

COUNTIF(A1:A6, 5)

=> result: 1

=> expected result: 4

I thought the problem was that the columns are formatted as numbers but converting them to strings does not solve it. I think I somehow need to split the values by COMMA and put them into an array?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds, although I was going to use `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*5*"),COUNTIF(A1:A6,5))`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook in your solution the 5 in "4,5" does not get counted. Rest works.

Comment: @DonMB  Good point - it's expected something after the 5 in *5*.  Also noticed now looking at FJT's answer it would also incorrectly count ,25,51,55 as 1 five whereas it should be 0 and 5,5,5,5 would count as 1 five.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want 55 to count,

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*,5,*")+COUNTIF(A1:A6,5)+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"5,*")+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*,5")
```

Comment: 4,5 does not get counted. Maybe a format prob? I tried to format the cell as "general" and as "text" with no success

Comment: Trailing spaces?

Answer (score 1):

If there will be only a single countable "5" in any given cell (and you do NOT want to count, for example `55`, then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&5&",",","&A1:A6&","))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the given values in a column A and you are trying to compare a field which is in cell B2, then the following formula should work.

```
COUNTIFS(A:A,"*" & B2 & "*")
```